# September 2018 - Photo competition

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Competition for September - theme: travelling selfie / photo of you. You must be in it.

Rules:

- 1 post per answer.
- May submit more than 1 answer per user.
- try and keep it non offensive
- User posting must appear in photo

Winner is the most upvoted photo during the month of September 2018.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not getting it. Is it only for answers?

Comment: @NeanDerThal it's just a photo comp. So during September, if you'd like to post a photo below (travelling selfie), we can upvote/downvote the best ones.  Just for fun, separate from the main site.

Comment: Maybe add a disclaimer about this permitting Facebook to link your Stack Exchange accounts to your (possibly shadow) profile, and similarly for other large and potentially "evil" organisations?

Comment: @mark thanks. I thought it's something about answers in the main site  what was i thinking

Comment: Does the selfie have to be taken during the month of September?

Comment: Also, does using a tripod with a timer count as a "selfie"? :)

Comment: The edit to the header does answer that, it has to be a photo with you in it. I took it that we can use older photos and I have not been slapped on the wrist yet.

Comment: So old photos are not permitted?

Comment: I think it should be photos taken in September. Otherwise we're just digging up our oldest and greatest.

Comment: @MarkMayo, you should have said so at the start of the month, when we discussed it in chat. My photo was taken a few years ago and I am not willing to take it down now you changed the rules.

Comment: Thought it was fairly obvious, that's how most photo competitions work, anywhere....but all good. Upload what you want :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My 'new role' serving alcohol in the business bar upstairs on the Emirates A380 on my flight to Nice this morning ;)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Sunshine City, Tokyo]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Puhŭng Station]

About to board the Pyongyang metro at Puhŭng Station - Sept 2014

Comment: Nice photo +1 

Answer (score 10):

Visiting the village Fucking in Austria

[image: selfie in Fucking]

Comment: nice photo man!

Answer (score 9):

If tripod/self timer photos are allowed: Here's me, looking towards the Mawddach Estuary from Fairbourne in Wales.

[image: Lizzan looking towards the Mawddach Estuary]

Answer (score 9):

[image]
*Own picture, CC-BY-NC-ND 4.0*

Here I am standing on the Hoba meteorite in Namibia during
our travel to the total eclipse in Zambia 2001. Yeah, I forgot
to draw the T-Shirt out.

Answer (score 8):

A photo taken in an underpass in Maidenhead, UK, [(under bridge road.)](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Bridge+Rd,+Maidenhead,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5237912,-0.7111653,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48766327f7175ee3:0x11db7690cab2d910!8m2!3d51.5237912!4d-0.7089766)

[image: A wall with little round mirrors, a person in one of them]
*Willeke in one of the mirrors,* photo taken by Willeke, free for all to use.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Willeke in front of a local map with 'you are here' sign]
As common by selfies, photo taken by Willeke.

Here a selfie taken in September 2018, in front of a 'you are here' marker on a local map.